# GET method redirect error

Tags: php

I have a edit URL on my webpage, and want to redirect to the same page and execute the code.

Example: test.php: edit url clicked -> test.php.

code test.php:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";  
 echo "<td><a href='test.php&id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";                 
 echo "</tr>";                  
}
```

Now I have the following code also in test.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
 echo "Test";
}
```

Output:
http://prntscr.com/2cauwi

Why does it not $_GET the ID and echo test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark is used as the separator. That's what separates your query string from the rest of the URL. In this case, the query string isn't separated properly (because you're using `&` as the separator) and it tries to access an incorrect page, causing a 404 error. The URL should be the following instead:

```
example.com/includes/test/test.php?id=14
                                  ^
```

You use `&` when you have multiple query parameters. For example:

```
example.com/includes/test/test.php?id=14&name=Foo
```

Comment: Yes thank you I did not noticed I used & instead of ? Thank you Amal!

Comment: @user3111229: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<td><a href='test.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
echo "<td><a href='test.php&id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>"
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href='test.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>"
```

Note the ? instead of the & the & is only used for subsequent parameters.

Comment: Aha I did know that, but did not noticed;) Thank you!